# SQL: count progressively unique visits from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table (visits):

```
id  |       fb_id    |   flipbook    | 
----     ----------      ---------     
1         1123           november2014        
2         1123           november2014      
3         1127           november2014       
4         1124           november2014    
5         1126           november2014            
6         1123           december2014
7         1124           december2014
8         1125           december2014
9         1123           january2015  
10         1124           january2015
11        1125           january2015
12         1123           february2015
13         1125           february2015
14        1124           february2015
15        1127           february2015
16        1129           march2015
17        1123           march2015
18        1123           march2015
19        1124           march2015
20        1125           march2015
21        1126           march2015
22        1128           march2015
```

We have 5 flipbooks in total, and after the query I want to get the following results:

```
5: 10 (because we have 2 users that visited all the flipbooks = 10 visits)
4: 4 (only 1 user visited 4 flipbooks = 4 visits)
3: 0
2: 4 (2 users visited  2 flipbook = 4 visits )
1: 2 (2 users visited only 1 flipbook = 2 visits)
```

I don't have any query in mind to post here to achive this result, any ideas?

Comment: Can you please expand on what your output should be? I don't understand the login.. what 5 users visited all the flipbooks?

Comment: The output can be 10, 4, 0, 4, 2, for example user 1123 and 1124 visied all the flipbooks so we have 2 users * 5 visits = 10, then user 1125 visited 4 flipbooks only so we have 1 user * 4 visits = 4 etc.

Comment: Is the number of flipbooks dynamic or can we assume that their number is fixed?

Comment: There is a new flipbook every month, but I can add it manually in the query once per month if that's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a subquery that counts the distinct flipbooks by fb_id. The outer query would count the inner counts and multiply them as well. You can use the concat() function if you want to get the results in a single field as t.visited:no_of_visits format without any additional subquery.

```
select t.visited, count(t.visited) * t.visited as no_of_visits
from
    (select fb_id, count(distinct flipbook) as visited
     from vistits group by fb_id) t
group by t.visited
```

Comment: Worked first try, thanks! Also thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Lachesis whether a suggested solution works in a copy/paste way should not determine if that's the best solution to a given problem! In many cases the answerers do not have the time or the opportunity to properly test their codes and some syntax errors may remain. You should make some effort next time trying to fix minor syntax errors in the answers and evaluate the different answers for their effectiveness as well.

Comment: Ok I agree, I will take all the blame, @Sagi upvoted, thanks for your time, I am just noob in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.cnt ||' : '|| s.cnt*s.cnt2 from (
SELECT p.cnt,count(*) cnt2 from (
SELECT t.fb_ind,count(distinct t.flipbook) as cnt from yourTable t
group by t.fb_ind) p
group by p.cnt) s
```

This is untested , so maybe there will need to be some syntax anjustments, but it should work.

First - distinct your table, then - group by for getting Num of flip visited, then - group by to see how many did the same flips, and then concate it and make your calc.

Comment: I get an error: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: No need for the innermost subselect, you can do the distinct within the count. If you make this change, then our solutions will be exactly the same.

Comment: @Lachesis This particular error message is quite explanatory, so you could also take some steps to resolve the error by fixing the above query.

Comment: There is no need for the outmost subquery, you can do the concatenation and the multiplication one level down.

Comment: @Shadow I know, but he seems rather new to sql so I wanted him to understand, my first post was as you say, but I decided to edit it